# Don't cancel the first observable if the second fails, how to keep it (forkJoin, zip). Angular 11

Tags: javascript, angular, angular11

I have parallel API calls. How to continue getting data from one of them if second one failed?

```
forkJoin([a,b])
      .subscribe({
        next: ((data) => {
          const [first, second] = data;
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that combineLatest is what you are looking for, with a catchError to each of your observables to manage errors. Something like:

```
combineLatest([
  obs1$.pipe(catchError(() => of(null)),
  obs2$.pipe(catchError(() => of(null)),
]).subscribe(([first, second]) => { console.log(first,second); });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have already found a solution, we need to handle errors in each observable and return of().

```
catchError(() => of([]))
```